# rearrangement of the series (analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

This problem is about rearranging the series. I think it is necessary to show  that partial sum of the series is dense in R (or could be Q). But I cannot go further. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the countable union of countable sets is still countable, we can make a sequence $\{r_1,r_2,\dots\}$ such that for each $r\in\mathbb Q$, $r=r_i$ for infinitely many values of $i$.  Furthermore, do it so that terms alternate signs, $r_1>0$, $r_2<0$, $r_3>0$, etc. (to see that this is possible, just do one such sequence just for $\mathbb Q^+$ and another for $\mathbb Q^-$ and then interweave the two sequences.)  Now we know $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n-1}$ diverges to $\infty$,  and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-\frac1{2n})$ diverges to $-\infty$.  So rearrange as follows.  Start with $0$ and start adding the odd (positive) terms (in order) until you get something greater than $r_1$, then start adding the even (negative) terms until you get something less than $r_2$, then start adding odd terms again until is is greater than $r_3$, etc..

Now, at the $i$-th step, the partial sum is of a distance to $r_i$ no more than the size of the last term $\pm\frac1n$ added.  Since the absolute value of those terms go to zero and since $r$ appears on the list infinitely many times, there is a partial sum arbitrarily close to $r\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Riemann's theorem is about rearranging to get a given number as the sum.  The problem at hand is different: Rearrange the series so that the partial sums form a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @zhw. Thank you, I was too hasty.  I tried to write up a proof from scratch, let me know if you think it doesn't work.